# VBA function that can filter a column on the basis of values in a different column

Tags: vba, excel

I've got the following list:

```
Equities
           Siemens
           Amazon
           UPS
Bonds 
           Treasuries
           Bunds
```

There are two different methods to treating the cost of these securities (1 method as a bond and another 1 as an equity) and I am trying to create a function that can encompasses both methods to calculate:

**IMPORTANT**: the range/list is dynamic. That means that the list is copied from another worksheet and thus if I add another equity to the list then the `Bond` title would move down a cell. This makes it considerably more difficult to create a cogent if-then statement.

**My idea:** I can assess the position of the cell (chosen as my argument) in relation to the cells in the first column. So the basic idea would be:

If //selected range is above Bonds then choose equity method 
Else //choose equity method

Caveat: The range is still dynamic, so how do I refer to `Bonds`?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Look into [Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) method and dynamically [finding last row](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)

Comment: And what about the position of the cells?

Comment: What do you mean? You can use Range.Find to determine the cell where Bonds is located and if found use .Row of returned range to determine row where found then use that for your comparison. You need to show your coding efforts as well and explain where you are stuck or the question risks being closed as too broad.

Comment: If Range.Find("Bonds").Row < rng.Row Then... right? whereby rng is the argument of my function

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the Range.Find("Bonds") to one column as I may have more than one "Bonds" on the worksheet

Comment: Yes. You use that column as the range e.g. Columns("D").Find("Bonds", SearchOrder:=xlByRows)